# Keyboard shortcuts for P4 Diff / P4 Folder Diff

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, perforce, p4v

I have searched the P4 documentation and knowledge bases and I cannot find if there are *any* keyboard shortcuts to perform common actions when diffing files.

I know about the next and previous change (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> respectively) however there are more common actions.

So, are there any **undocumented** keyboard shortcuts that you know?

For example:

- Merge changes per line (i.e., select change on left or right, or revert to base).
- Open the left or right for editing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing that I know of, but the 2012.1 release of P4V does support configurable keyboard shortcuts.  I'm not sure if that's extending into P4Merge, but it'd be worth asking for the feature.

Comment: If you wish to vote up the feature request, [here is the p4ideax page "Driving P4Merge entirely using the keyboard"](http://www.p4ideax.com/ideas/13492/driving-p4merge-entirely-using-the-keyboard).